# wpf set the content of datagrid's selected templatecolumn's textbox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I need to find out how to pass a string to `ComboBox` that's inside of a `TemplateColumn` of a `DataGrid`. The idea behind is that whenever I double-click on a `TextBox` a `Popup` appears and I select the new content of the `TextBox` from it (`ComboBox` inside a `Popup`).

**XAML**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="unit">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding unit}" MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick_1" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<!-- The columns in the grid are binded to DataTable-->

<!-- Popup -->
<Popup Name="unitpop" StaysOpen="True" VerticalOffset="-20" HorizontalOffset="30" Placement="Mouse" >
    <Grid Width="100" Height="20" Background="Transparent" >
        <ComboBox x:Name="unit_combo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UnitListData}}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="idunit" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="unit_combo_SelectionChanged" />
    </Grid>
</Popup>

<!-- The ComboBox is binding an ObservableCollection -->
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `ComboBox` instead of `TextBox` in your CellTemplate? In this way, user could select the value directly and no `Popup` is needed.

Comment: I don't think it is much of a help to just recommend using something else. Apparently if I am asking this question I have a reason not to use ComboBox inside of a TemplateColumn. Not trying to be rude, just saying.

Comment: Never mind. I am just trying to find another way to solve the problem. You know, we may get stuck by ourselves sometimes when trying to find a solution which is quite apparent for someone else. :)

Comment: Please see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997951/how-to-access-datagrid-template-column-textbox-text-wpf-c-sharp. I hope this helps.

Comment: It works, the only problem is that I get only the first one that I click on. Do you have any idea how to fix it? (I put the code into SelectionChanged event)

Comment: I had forgotten that in this case will return only the first row. Please see my edit.