# How to reference TextBox in Datagrid Template column

Tags: datagrid

How can I reference textbox in the column header. I trying to disable button based on textbox value. 
How can I reference textbox in the column header. I trying to disable button based on textbox value.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgEmp">
 <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonDisable" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtItemName, Path=Text}" Value=""/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Item Detail-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="Item Name" />
                        <TextBox Name="txtItemName" Text=""/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Name="btnInsert" Content="Insert" 
                            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ButtonDisable}"                 
                            Click="btnInsert_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Have you tried ItemDataBound Event ?

Comment: DataGrid column headers have text boxes and the last column header has Button. I want button to remain "Disabled" if any of the text boxes are empty.  I am new to WPF.

Comment: I have to reference something like this  DataGrid.DataGridHeaderColumn[x].find("texboxt_I_looking_for"). I am not sure about the format, I am guessing based on my Asp.NET past

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997951/how-to-access-datagrid-template-column-textbox-text-wpf-c-sharp

Comment: I have done something similar to in Button Click event to commit data (textbox values) to database. I am trying to do something with triggers in xaml to disable button not in code behind.