# How to access XAML button from code behind WPF

Tags: wpf, button, datagrid, window, dockpanel

My code:

```
<DataGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  BorderBrush="#83D744" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" Grid.Column="0"   RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  x:Name="datagrid1" Margin="10,150,8,50" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="#FF494949"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#83D744"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        </Style>


<Style x:Key="TextInCellCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="RightAligElementStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="LeftAligElementStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
           Color="Transparent"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>


<DataGrid.Columns >
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}"     ElementStyle="{StaticResource LeftAligElementStyle}"     Header="NAZIV ARTIKLA" MinWidth="350"    Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}"        ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}"         Header="KOLIČINA"   MinWidth="200" Foreground="White"      FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
</DataGrid.Columns>

<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True"  Background="Black" Opacity="0.7">
                                <Expander.Header >
                                    <DockPanel Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Name="dockPanel" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=ActualWidth}">

                                        <Button Name="btnFinishOrder" Content="Finish Order" Margin="0,0,55,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Click="btnFinishOrder_Click" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#83D744"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#83D744" Width="130"   Height="40">
                                             <Button.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                        BorderBrush=    "{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                        Background=     "{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                </Border>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                             </Button.Template>
                                         </Button>

                                         <Button Name="btnTakeIt" Click="btnTakeIt_Click"  Content="Take it" Margin="0,0,20,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#83D744"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#83D744" Width="130"   Height="40">
                                             <Button.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                </Border>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                             </Button.Template>
                                        </Button>
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" Height="25" Foreground="#83D744" Text="{Binding Path=Name,StringFormat= Number of Order:# {0}}" />

                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander.Content>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

[image]

**There you can see guys, when I click on button `Click="btnTakeIt_Click"` I programaticaly change buttons text to "Order in progress." and I update field in my database `IsInProgres` to 1 - true, code is here:**

```
 private void btnTakeIt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;

        CollectionViewGroup group = b.DataContext as CollectionViewGroup;
        var x = group.Name;
        int orderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(x);

        b.BorderBrush = null;
        b.Content = "Order is in progress";
        b.FontSize = 12;

        OrdersController.SetOrderInProgressByID(orderNumber);

    }
```

But what is happening, because I'm refreshing my grid every 20 seconds my button content is becoming again like it's on default "Take it!" because that's whats written in XAML.

Like this:
[image]

This is my code behind (refresh every few seconds):

```
 public MainWindow()
{
    try
    {


        InitializeComponent();


        this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

        var ordersList = OrdersController.localOrders();


        collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
        collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("NumberOfOrder"));
        DataContext = collectionViewSource;

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var ordersList = OrdersController.localOrders();
    collectionViewSource.Source = null;
    collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;

    DataContext = collectionViewSource;

    datagrid1.ScrollIntoView(datagrid1.Items[datagrid1.Items.Count - 1]);
}
```

}

So my question is could I somehow loop my localOrders and check if `NumberOfOrder` has `IsInProgress = 1` and simply set this:

```
btnTakeIt.Content="Order in progress.."
```

So everytime my grid refresh I can loop my orders, and check is order `InProgress` and after that I can set button btnTakeIt content to "Order in progress.."

Or if there is any other way, I am opened to try it!

P.S I tried allready but my btnTakeIt is not accessible in code behind :(

EDIT:

```
 void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button MyButton = FindChild<Button>(datagrid1, "btnTakeIt");

        var ordersList = OrdersController.localOrders();
        collectionViewSource.Source = null;
        collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
        foreach (var item in ordersList)
        {
            if (item.IsInProgress== true)
            {
                MyButton.Content = "Order is in progress";
            }
        }

        DataContext = collectionViewSource;


    }
```

Can I do it like this? I checked debuger and it is entering inside of if statement and when I look at breakpoint it acctualy changes content but on grid I can not see anything changed :(

EDIT:

[image]

I have to mention that my class Product is contained in my OrdersController :)

@Ayuman
what do you think about this:

```
<Button Name="btnTakeIt"   DataContext="{Binding Items[0]}" Content="{Binding Status}"Click="btnTakeIt_Click"  Content="Take it" Margin="0,0,20,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#83D744"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#83D744" Width="130"   Height="40">
                                         <Button.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                            </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                         </Button.Template>
                                    </Button>
```

code behind:

```
 public static List<LocalOrders> localOrders()
    {
        var results = DataServices.POS.proc_GetAllOrders().ToList();


        List<LocalOrders> localOrdersList = new List<LocalOrders>();

        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            LocalOrders lokal = new LocalOrders();
            if (item.IsInProgress)
            {
                localo.Pihvacena = true;
                localo.Status = "IN PROCESS";
            }
            else
            {
                lokalne.Status = "IT IS NOT YET IN PROCESS";
            }


            lokal.User = item.User;
            lokal.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(item.Quantity);
            lokal.Title = item.Title;
            lokal.NumberOfOrder = item.NumberOfOrder;
            localOrdersList.Add(lokal);
        }
        return localOrdersList;
    }
```

So I can programaticaly check for status of order and set content of button like that.. is it good solution maybe?

Comment: You can use traverse the visual tree using the method suggested in the post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997951/how-to-access-datagrid-template-column-textbox-text-wpf-c-sharp

Comment: @Ayyappan Subramanian I made edit following post from your link, Can you take a look at edit mate, I did somethinh wrong probably, I find button and it s content but I can not change it on that way. Check for edit dude

Comment: I think you are not changing the Text both the text says "Order is in progress".

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian So what should I do mate? :) thanks a lot

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian I tested with different text nothing is happening, maybe I did something wrong there...

Comment: Can you add a full sample with dummy data?

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian How do you mean full sample? full code or?

Comment: Added answer check and let me know if it works

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian,  I will try it as soon as possible I saw that you changed a lot on code behind also, dont you?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code. I tried to make it work. Hope this works for you as well

```
 <DataGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  BorderBrush="#83D744" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" Grid.Column="0"   RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  x:Name="datagrid1" Margin="10,150,8,50" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="#FF494949"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#83D744"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            </Style>


            <Style x:Key="TextInCellCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="RightAligElementStyle">
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="LeftAligElementStyle">
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            </Style>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
       Color="Transparent"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>


        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}"     ElementStyle="{StaticResource LeftAligElementStyle}"     Header="NAZIV ARTIKLA" MinWidth="350"    Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}"        ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}"         Header="KOLIČINA"   MinWidth="200" Foreground="White"      FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True"  Background="Black" Opacity="0.7">
                                        <Expander.Header >
                                            <DockPanel Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Name="dockPanel" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=ActualWidth}">

                                                <Button Name="btnFinishOrder" DataContext="{Binding Items[0]}" Content="{Binding ButtonCaption}" Margin="0,0,55,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Click="BtnFinishOrder_OnClick" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#83D744"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#83D744" Width="130"   Height="40">
                                                    <Button.Template>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                    BorderBrush=    "{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                    Background=     "{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Button.Template>
                                                </Button>

                                                <Button Name="btnTakeIt" Click="BtnTakeIt_OnClick"  DataContext="{Binding Items[0]}" Content="{Binding ButtonCaption}" Margin="0,0,20,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#83D744"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#83D744" Width="130"   Height="40">
                                                    <Button.Template>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Button.Template>
                                                </Button>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" Height="25" Foreground="#83D744" Text="{Binding Items[0].ProductName}" />

                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ICollectionView view;
    private ObservableCollection<Product> ordersList;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

        ordersList = new ObservableCollection<Product>()
        {
            new Product()
            {
                ProductName = "Prodct",
                Quantity = 1,
                NumberOfOrder = 100,
                IsInProgress = true,
                ButtonCaption = "Take it"
            },
            new Product()
            {
                ProductName = "Prodct1",
                Quantity = 2,
                NumberOfOrder = 1000,
                ButtonCaption = "Take it"

            },
            new Product()
            {
                ProductName = "Prodct2",
                Quantity = 3,
                NumberOfOrder = 10000,
                ButtonCaption = "Take it"

            },
            new Product()
            {
                ProductName = "Prodct3",
                Quantity = 4,
                NumberOfOrder = 100000,
                ButtonCaption = "Take it"

            },
        };

        view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ordersList);

        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("NumberOfOrder"));
        DataContext = view;

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick; ;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in ordersList)
        {
            if (item.IsInProgress)
            {
                item.ButtonCaption = "Order is Still in progress";
            }
        }
    }

    private void BtnFinishOrder_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void BtnTakeIt_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;

        Product prod = b.DataContext as Product;

        b.BorderBrush = null;
        prod.ButtonCaption = "Order is in progress";
        b.FontSize = 12;
    }
}

class Product:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string productName;

    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return productName ; }
        set
        {
            productName = value ;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
        }
    }

    private int quantity;

    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set
        {
            quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
        }
    }

    public int NumberOfOrder { get; set; }

    public bool IsInProgress { get; set; }

    private string buttonCaption;

    public string ButtonCaption
    {
        get { return buttonCaption; }
        set
        {
            buttonCaption = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ButtonCaption");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mate I will leave you reply tomorrow, allready checked this, tomorrow I will implement it and leave you reply does it work. + Do I need to implement PropertyChangedEventHandler and OnPropertyChanged method? I need them all?

Comment: Modified my propertychanged notification. Check now